# RPi Python server that I can access anywhere

Tags: python, json, raspberry-pi

I want to make my Raspberry Pi to run a server application in python so that, with my client application on my mac, I could send json requests to it so the Raspberry Pi would preform certain actions based on the json request. I want to know:

1. Which ports should I use? (I think my verizon FiOS router blocks certain ports
2. should I use raspian for this project?
3. How can I get a static IP for my pi?

Comment: Try one of the sister sites: [Raspberry Pi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the 3rd problem you can use [no-ip.com](http://www.noip.com/). This won't give you a static ip, but will map your dynamic one to a url.